# creating a single admin with rails_admin for admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` with devise, and  I want to only allow a *single user* to access/admin, otherwise, redirect user to home page.

How do I implement this in a clean code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it into your application controller. First you need to define role for admin.

Example:
In your **ApplicationController**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
    rails_admin_path
  elsif current_user && current_user.superadmin?
    rails_admin_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```